# AWS S3 URL CNAME 403 Issue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

**The urls that work to my content are**

`https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>`
   `http://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>`
   `<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>`
   `s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<object>`

**I want this URL to work**

`<bucket>/<object>`

but it isn't working.

**This code works**

`$request = $client->get("http://{$bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{$s3name}");`
   `return $client->createPresignedUrl($request, $time);`

**This code doesn't**

`$request = $client->get("http://{$bucket}/{$s3name}");`
   `return $client->createPresignedUrl($request, $time);`

Can somebody help me out here? Do I have to have https to make this work? I added the CNAME too.

Answer (score 1):

When signing a request for a bucket you'll access with the "s3.amazon..." component in the hostname, the string-to-sign includes the resource, which looks like this:

```
/bucket/object
```

The natural conclusion is that if you're using a virtual-hosted bucket, then the resource would look like this:

```
/object
```

However, that's not correct.  You still need the bucket name before the object name in the string to sign, even though it's not included in the path portion of the url (since s3 picks it up from the Host: header).

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

To verify this, you could manually take the signed URL generated by the code you showed under "this code works," change the hostname to your bucket name, remove the bucket from the path, and your should find that the signature is still valid even though you've manually rewritten the url to the desired format.

Comment: Yes I have already tried that. It looks like it is redirecting right but I don't have permissions to access the file. The page says `403 Forbidden

Code: AccessDenied
Message: Access Denied
RequestId: 6BABFAE0FAE788D7
HostId: 8PKrtuqW2DU+T3YXhcyBkkvj0RM3w04ojZTCe9NvxRXPu522Bi1FWTC7eR3mNgm0`

Comment: That's possible but if you're able to access it one way, you should be able to access the other if the signing credentials are the same... is your bucket name is all lowercase, no special characters other than dashes or digits, 63 total characters or less, and in DNS, "your.bucket.com" is configured as a CNAME pointing to "your.bucket.com.s3.amazonaws.com"?

Comment: Yes. I can view public content at <bucket>/<object> but I can't view private signed urls from the AWS SDK PHP 2 API that are <bucket>/<object>?<params>

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use Virtual Hosting: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

This involves two parts - first, set up a CNAME with your desired hostname. Next, make sure you send the correct hostname when making the request. From the docs:

```
GET /homepage.html HTTP/1.1
Host: johnsmith.net.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: I did do this CNAME stuff. The CNAME is files.<myurl>.com that points to <bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com.

Comment: CNAME is only one part. Are you also sending the correct host header when making your request?

Comment: Yes. I can view public content at <bucket>/<object> but I can't view private signed urls from the AWS SDK PHP 2 API that are <bucket>/<object>?<params>. I can view private files that are <bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<object>.